# scheme - function with let

Tags: scheme

I saw that a similar question was asked before, but I don't understand another issue here.

Here are two functions:

```
(define x 2)
(define a 2)

(define goo
  (lambda (x)
    (display x)
    (lambda (y) (/ x y))))

(define foo
  (let ((f (goo a)))
    (lambda (x)
      (if (= x 0)
          x
          (f x)))))
```

What is the return value of `(foo (foo 0))`? What will print out to the screen?

As I understand it, when I run `(foo 0)` in the beginning, `2` will print out (we will enter the function `goo`), and the return value will be `0`. Then, we will enter the function `foo` again with `(foo (foo 0))` => `(foo 0)`. We again enter the function `goo` and `2` will print out. But when I run it, `2` is printed just once. I think I'm missing a critical issue about `let` and its connection to `lambda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `let` inside the definition of `foo`, and therefore the application of `goo` to `a`, is evaluated when `foo` is defined, not when `foo` is evaluated.

Look at it this way: what is the value of foo? It is the `lambda` expression. The binding of `f` is closed over by `foo`, it is not "redone" every time `foo` is evaluated.

Edit: here's an example without `lambda`s

```
> (let ((x (sqrt 2))) (* x 3))
4.24264068711929
> (define bar (let ((x (sqrt 2))) (* x 3)))
> bar
4.24264068711929
>
```

When you evaluate `bar` you are not calling `sqrt` again. `bar` is defined as the body of the `let`, in this case a number that is the result if an expression.

In your example the body of the `let` is a `lambda` expression. But just like my example, the `let` binding is not re-executed.

Comment: Tank u. But the body of the "let" is:
(lambda (x)
      (if (= x 0)
          x
          (f x)))
meaning - I have to enter the let every time I evaluated "foo". Because that, I have also enter the function "goo" (re-defind). 
What Im missing?

Comment: You evaluate f again when x is non-zero; but f is the result of evaluating (goo a) when foo is defined; f is already bound, it is not rebound every time you execute foo.